# $compile:ctreq error in angular code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to write a directive to create tab in angular but its giving $compile:ctreq in console everytime I am running the code.
here is my code app.js

```
(function(window) {

angular.module('app', [])
.directive('tab', function() {
  return {
restrict: 'E',
transclude: true,
template: '<h2>Hello world!</h2> <div role="tabpanel" ng-transclude></div>',
require: '^tabset',
scope: {
    heading: '@'
},
link: function(scope, elem, attr,tabsetCtrl) {
     //tabsetCtrl.addTab(scope)
}
  }
})
 .directive('tabset', function() {
return {
restrict: 'E',
transclude: true,
scope: { },
templateUrl: 'tabset.html',
bindToController: true,
controllerAs: 'tabset',
controller: function() {
    var self = this
    self.tabs = []

    /* self.addTab = function addTab(tab) {
      self.tabs.push(tab)
    } */
    }
  }
})
})(window);
```

here is my index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Tabs Directive</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  <h1>Tabs, tabs, tabs!</h1>
 </tabset>
 <tab heading="Tab 1">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut eam nullam utroque liberavisse, ea
  </tab>
 <tab heading="Tab 2">
    Just another tab!
 </tab>
 </tabset>
</body>
```

here is my tabset.html

```
<div role="tabpanel">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation"
      ng-repeat="tab in tabset.tabs">

      <a href=""
        role="tab"
        ng-click="tabset.select(tab)">{{tab.heading}}</a>
    </li>
    </ul>

  <ng-transclude>
  </ng-transclude>
</div>
```

I am not able to understand what wrong am i doing.
Actually there are my objectives

1. create a tab system like chrome.where I can add tabs dynamically and the template of the tab will be also dynamic.
2. each template will have different controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tabset tags in the `index.html` are both closing tags, which means that angular doesn't compile the tabset, and the tab directive can't require tabset:

```
 </tabset> <!-- closing tag should be <tabset> -->
 <tab heading="Tab 1">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut eam nullam utroque liberavisse, ea
  </tab>
 <tab heading="Tab 2">
    Just another tab!
 </tab>
 </tabset> <!-- closing tag -->
```